# GET 400 (Bad Request) with node in js

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, response

I have this js

```
    var https = require('https');

    var contador =process.argv[2]?process.argv[2]:'...';
    var screen_name =process.argv[3]?process.argv[3]:'...';
    var user_id =process.argv[4]?process.argv[4]:'...';

    var options = {
        host: 'api.twitter.com',
        path: '/1.1/followers/ids.json/count/'+contador+'/screen_name/'+screen_name+'/user_id/'+user_id,
        method: 'GET'
    };
var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log('Response is '+res.statusCode);
                         res.setEncoding('utf8');
                         res.on('data', function (datos_JSON) {
                                 var datos=JSON.parse(datos_JSON);
                 });

 });
```

req.end();

and I get the following error, response 400, why?...

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of problems:

1. The docs state the EITHER a user_name OR a screen_name need to be provided, not both.
2. These things are to be provided as query string parameters, not path parameters
3. You need to authenticate first. The Twitter API is not open, you generally need to be acting on behalf of an authenticated user (though there is Application auth available too).

Here's an example URL from the docs: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=sitestreams&count=5000

- Read the docs about the followers API: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/followers/ids
- Learn about the authentication: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth (for users) and https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth (for applications)